# Image does not contain a definition for "FromStream"

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm grabbing a ByteString from my gRPC service and I'm trying to display it in a Maui app. I keep getting an error that's preventing the code from running I've tried multiple different ways to fix this.

What I'm currently doing

```cs
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes.ToByteArray()))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(ms); // from stream is the error
            }
```

I've also tried

```cs
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

            Image x = (Bitmap)(new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(bytes.ToByteArray()));
```

There are a bunch of errors from this one aswell.

I have a reference to System.Drawing, but its grayed out. Inspecting the Image variable its referencing the 'Microsoft.Maui.Contols.Image' class and from this article [it's a different class.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image?view=net-maui-7.0#load-an-image-from-a-stream)

```
Image image = new Image
{
    Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream)
};
```

Comment: I added this ```
            Image image = new Image
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes.ToByteArray()))
            };
            image.Source = image.Source;``` but the image still doenst load. Is it possibly not in the correct file format?

Comment: are you adding `image` to the page?  If you create an image source using a local image or a static url does it appear?

Comment: yeah i used this image https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png and it loaded

Comment: well really what i did was image.Source = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png";

Comment: are you sure `bytes` contains valid image data?

Comment: Very certain. Is there any way to verify?

Comment: write to a file and load from there, and/or validate with an image tool

Comment: Honestly I'm really new to C# and I'm trying to write it as a bitmap so I can just load write to the file. Should I just create a file and then go through the byte array and insert each index?

Comment: where are you getting `bytes` from?  What kind of image format is it?  You can write an entire `byte[]` at once with `File.WriteAllBytes()`

Comment: I'm getting the bytes from the gRPC service as a ByteString (the class has a ByteArray field), also I found out that it is empty the size of the array is zero.

Comment: well, that would be the root of your problem

Comment: I forgot to send this earlier, but the problem is fixed. I called a different rpc and which had the image size.